# CORS issue with Chome and Node ExpressJS Server

Tags: express, cors

I've got a Chrome CORS issues using AngularJS and Node ExpressJS server.

I've read many posts with the same issue and I've implemented the solutions but still no joy.

Hoping another set of eyes can see where I'm going wrong.

I'm in development local box and going

```
From AngularJS app: http://localhost:3000

To Node ExpressJS Server : http://localhost:3001

Error is:
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:3001/api/v1/articles. 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Node ExpressJS configs are standard recommended:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:3000');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST,GET,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS');
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Cache-Control, Pragma, Origin, Authorization, Content-Type, X-Requested-With");
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
next();
});
```

When doing the post from the browser here's Chrome's pre-flight request to the server:

Request Headers:

```
OPTIONS /api/v1/articles HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:3001
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Origin: http://localhost:3000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)     Chrome/31.0.1650.57 Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers: accept, content-type
Accept: */*
Referer: http://localhost:3000/
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

Response Headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Cache-Control, Pragma, Origin, Authorization, Content-Type, X-Requested-With
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:POST,GET,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://localhost:3000
Allow:GET
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:3
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Tue, 03 Dec 2013 19:24:22 GMT
```

POST Request headers:

```
POST http://localhost:3001/api/v1/articles HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Referer: http://localhost:3000/
Origin: http://localhost:3000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.57 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
```

Then the console error appears and no post.

The server configs, pre-flight options request and Access-Control headers all look to be correct to me.

Can you see an issue?

The `Allow:GET` header in the OPTIONS response is something I'm not sure about.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you include a snippet of your client side code? You have the `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true` set, are you setting the corresponding `xhr.withCredentials=true` property on your XMLHttpRequest object?

Comment: Are those the actual `POST` request headers? If so, why does it include a full URL instead of just a path (as with the `OPTIONS` request)?

Comment: @monsur here's some of the relevant code: HTML:

    <form data-ng-submit="create()">
    <button type="submit">Create</button>

AngularJS Controller:

    $scope.create = function () {

    var article = {
    title: $scope.title,
    body $scope.body
    };

    Restangular.all('articles').post(article).then(
    function (success) {
    // locate to view path
    $location.path('/article/' + success._id);
    });

Comment: and Restangular config:

    angular.module('myApp')
    .config(function (RestangularProvider) {

    RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl('http://localhost:3001/api/v1');

    RestangularProvider.setDefaultHttpFields({withCredentials: true});
    });

Comment: @robertklep .. complete OPTIONS headers are: Request URL:http://localhost:3001/api/v1/rideshares
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:200 OK

Request Headersview parsed
OPTIONS /api/v1/rideshares HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:3001
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Origin: http://localhost:3000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.57 Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers: accept, content-type
Accept: */*
Referer: http://localhost:3000/
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8

Comment: GET is working fine, it's just POST, PUT, DELETE all being rejected

Comment: You don't seem to be setting a proper `baseUrl` for Restangular. Try prefixing it with `http://` (-> `RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl('http://localhost:3001/api/v1')`) (although if the `GET` works, that might not be an issue...)

Comment: I do have it prefixed with http:// it's just the comment formatting that makies it appear that way in the comment.

Answer (score 0):

I worked out a solution that I'm happy with.

I've put it over here in this question:

[CORS AngularJS Not Sending Cookie/Credentials with POST or DELETE but GET OK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20427778/cors-angularjs-not-sending-cookie-credentials-with-post-or-delete-but-get-ok)